# pypdf copying over original passwords when encrypting

Tags: pdf, encryption, aes, pypdf

I'm working on migrating from PyPDF2 to pypdf and running into some difficulty with copying over the original document passwords to the pdf. Here's a scenario:

- create a pdf with a user password and owner password
- encrypt and close the pdf
- open the pdf again with the owner password and decrypt it
- make some changes (append a page)
- encrypt again and close the pdf

The thing is I want my pdf to have the old user password still there. Is it possible to copy over the current encryption to the PDFWriter and add another encryption to it?

In PyPDF2 you would save the \Encrypt value and PDFFileReader.decryption_key and copy it to the writer and then call encrypt.

I tried playing with writer._ID, writer._encryption, and writer._encrypt_entry but I don't think I'm doing the right combination or something.

Here's how it was done in PyPDF2:
[image]

Comment: I'm creating my own PDF class that uses pypdf. A user would save the user_pwd and owner_pwd and encrypt the pdf. Then they'll open it again later with the owner_pwd and make changes and encrypt again. The original user_pwd needs to still be there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Im still a little lost though. please check my image

Comment: this isn't the answer I'm looking for. If I do writer.encrypt(user_pwd, owner_pwd) and reader.decrypt(owner_pwd). Then when I call writer.encrypt() how would I ensure the original user_pwd is copied over. Which protected attributes would this involve? _encryption, _encrypt_entry, etc.?

Comment: If I read it as an owner, I only know the owner_password for decrypt/encrypt not the original user_password someone set. I feel like it is more complicated. The image above showed a working example for my scenario in pypdf2.

Comment: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/discussions/2079